# How to remember if we use v.function() or function(v)?

Tags: python

please I want to know a way to remember or to easy difference between using 
v.function() or function(v) in python # v is a variable or object

```
capitalize(c) #error
c.capitalize() # OK

c="hello"
c.capitalize()
```

Comment: Your question is very vague.

Comment: I have  a problem when using function or method with python 
v.function() and function(v)
I hope to know how easy difference between this two types of using function in python

Comment: While there are some conventions, e.g. active `sort` as a method and passive/adjective `sorted` as a function, there are no rules enforcing this. You would have to at least specify which library you mean - even then it may not be consistent enough. Note that `str.capitalize(c)` *does* work in python.

Comment: I speak in generally if there is a way to know directly using str.capitalize() or capitalize(str) |||| object.function() or function(object)

Comment: In addition to what @MisterMiyagi said, one should be familiar with packages they use and refer to docs if uncertain. Also using IDE - with autocomplete, intellisense etc. could help. But the main is to know your tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version calls a function with `v` as an argument, the second one calls a method of the object `v`. Which one it is in a particular case may vary depending on the design approach, but in general:

1) If it modifies the state of an object, it's likely a method.

Examples: `list.sort()`, `dict.pop()`.

2) If it works on a variety of similar types, e.g. on containers, it's likely a function.

Examples: `len()`, `sum()`, `sorted()`.

3) If it object type specific and has to know something about the object implementation internals, it's likely a method.

Examples: `str.capitalize()`, `str.split()`.

4) If in doubt - refer to the documentation.